# error loading page - domain page undefined Erro code -1 ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITED

Tags: android, react-native

he creado un webview para android mi url a la que apunta mi webview aún no tiene dominio como tal entonces por ende no tiene https

al momento de crear mi apk y correrlo en una dispositivo fisico
sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he visto está publicación

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358411/react-native-after-running-signed-apk-undefiend-code-1-error-displaying-https

pero, no se exactamente donde incluir
donde dice :

```
create file at res/xml/react_native_config.xml
```

Ya que no hay un xml en la carpetas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi manifest.xml

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ligafut">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Cleartext es para dominios sin seguridad, tienees que poner a true para que permita el acceso a ese dominio no seguro.

Comment: @OsAndNoTi pero eso donde se pone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es provocado porque estas usando una url http:// , recuerda que a partir de Android 9 (API nivel 28), la compatibilidad "ClearText" está deshabilitada de forma predeterminada y debes habilitarla para soportar http:// , en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` agrega

```
<application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero: click derecho en la carpeta `res`-> `New` -> `Directory` y le pones de nombre `xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como verás, se nos creó la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segundo: click derecho en la carpeta que se nos creó (`xml`) -> `New` -> `File`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y le agregas el nombre `react_native_config.xml`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verás, se nos creó el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tercero, queda agregar el código pertinente a la configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuarto, debes agregar ese archivo creado a tu `manifest`:

```
    tools:targetApi="28"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/react_native_config"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]