# Cargar ruta de Google Maps a través de una URL

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, geolocalización

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación que carga localizaciones y rutas a través de google maps.

Utilizo un `MapView` para cargar la localización a través de coordenadas

```
        val sydney = LatLng((-34).toDouble(), 151.0)
        mapaRuta!!.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(sydney)
                .title("Sydney")
        )
        val zoomLevel = 16.0f
        mapaRuta!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,zoomLevel))
```

Mi duda es si puedo cargar una ruta al mapa a través de un enlace (https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?amp%3Busp=sharing&mid=1sbSQ-Cx_0PJ2Cj3BfPiJGL5FSYNbR0OY&ll=36.72192002039465%2C-4.416735350000005&z=17) en vez de usar las coordenadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar Google Maps, tendrías que obtener los valores de latitud y longitud de la url de otra forma para cargar la ruta mediante un enlace lo que tienes que realizar es usar un `Webview`:

```
web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?amp%3Busp=sharing&mid=1sbSQ-Cx_0PJ2Cj3BfPiJGL5FSYNbR0OY&ll=36.72192002039465%2C-4.416735350000005&z=17");
WebSettings mywebsettings = web.getSettings();
mywebsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

de esta forma se mostraría en el mapa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando pongo el enlace no se muestra nada, me sale una pantalla en blanco. En cambio, si quito la S del HTTP me muestra un error.

Comment: Habilita Javascript y configura un WebViewClient, actualicé la respuesta. Actualmente para poder usar urls no cifradas http:// debes habilitarlo dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml, revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392476/error-loading-page-domain-page-undefined-erro-code-1-err-cleartext-not-permit/392485#392485 @Alejandro

Comment: Va perfectamente, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Excelente saludos @Alejandro